# I need to pickle an array of (hardly pickable) class members

Tags: python, pickle

I have some class instances that I pickle using `__reduce__`. These classes have members that I collect in another array. I need to pickle this array, but I can't find the right way to do it.
Just to clarify things, imagine I have classes that represent square, rectangle and circle. I create some instances:

```
A=Square(10)
B=Rectangle(5,10)
C=Circle(6)
```

I can pickle the list

```
classes=[A, B, C]
```

but I need a way to pickle this array of the class instances properties

```
dimensions=[A.side, B.y, C.diameter]
```

keeping the reference to the original objects so that if one object changes the relative property changes: imagine I call `C.grow(2)` I expect to have `dimensions[2]=12`.

To solve the problem I now pickle this dictionary:

```
d={   classes: [A, B, C],
   dimensions: [(A,'side'), (B,'y'), (C,'diameter')] }
```

but I think this is a very poor solution.

I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: `A`, `B`, and `C` aren't classes, they're class instances. If you have a list of them, `instances = [A, B, C]`, then, even after pickle/unpickling, you should be able to access `instances[0].side`, `instances[1].y`, etc.

Comment: Your code is difficult to understand because it doesn't follow the [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) Python coding guidelines which say to only capitalize type name (like `Square`), but only use lowercase variable names.

Comment: @martineau my problem is that, after unpickling, I don't know what member I need for every item of _instances_... that's why I pickle also the _dimensions_ list.

Comment: Then you need to somehow store type information as well as instance in the list or make sure all instances have a common method you could call to get the information you need. Lastly, you could just check each instance's type with `instance[i],__class__` to know what attribute to access, but that is not very object-oriented.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to keep the original reference of the objects if you have things like `A.side` which is an int is to either keep it in a list or a class of it's own.

For example, you can do this:

```
class Value:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val
```

Now, you can make `Square`, `Rectangle` and `Circle` such that they use the class `Value` for each of their variables.

```
class Square:
    def __init__(self, side_length):
        self.side = Value(side_length)
```

and then use it in dimensions like `dimensions = [A.side, ...]`

Note, now that A.side is a class - the value cannot be seen using `print(A.side)` but can be seen using `print(A.side.value)`

Comment: `side` is an integer in my example but in the real code it is yet a class. That class is from a library and it is not pickable and I don't want to modify that library.

Answer (score 0):

I came out with this solution:

```
class AttributeWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, obj, attribute):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'ref_obj', obj)
        object.__setattr__(self, 'ref_attribute', attribute)

    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        return object.__getattribute__(self,'ref_obj').__getattribute__(object.__getattribute__(self,'ref_attribute')).__getattribute__(attr)

    def __setattr__(self,attr,value):
        object.__getattribute__(self,'ref_obj').__getattribute__(object.__getattribute__(self,'ref_attribute')).__setattr__(attr,value)
        return value
```

I don't think this is the ideal solution but, at least, with it I don't have to change the other classes (Square, Rectangle, Circle in the example).

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that your class methods are not able to be pickled, then you might try `dill`.  It typically *can* pickle class instances, class methods, and instance methods.

```
>>> import dill
>>> 
>>> class Square(object):
...   def __init__(self, side):
...     self.side = side
... 
>>> class Rectangle(object):
...   def __init__(self, x, y):
...     self.x = x
...     self.y = y
... 
>>> class Circle(object):
...   def __init__(self, diameter):
...     self.diameter = diameter
... 
>>> a = Square(10)
>>> b = Rectangle(5, 10)
>>> c = Circle(6)
>>> 
>>> dimensions = [a.side, b.x, b.y, c.diameter]
>>> _dim = dill.dumps(dimensions)
>>> 
>>> dim_ = dill.loads(_dim)
>>> dim_
[10, 5, 10, 6]
>>>
```